# Extracting a string within a string and omitting the search string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
string="soupnot$23.99dedarikjdf$44.65 notworryfence$98.44coyoteugle$33.94rock$2,300.00"
```

I want to extract the numbers `23.99, 44.65, 98.44,33.44, 2,300.00`. I have this regex

```
\$(.*[^\s])
```

There are 2 issues with this.

1. It returns the '$' sign.  I only want the number.
2. It only works when there is a space at the end of the number but sometimes there might be letters and it won't work in that case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex as shown:

```
import re
string="soupnot$23.99dedarikjdf$44.65 notworryfence$98.44coyoteugle$33.94rock$2,300.00"

res = re.findall(pattern="[\d.,]+", string=string)
```

**output:**

```
['23.99', '44.65', '98.44', '33.94', '2,300.00']
```

Comment: Please explain what does " [\d.,]+ " do

Comment: [] Used to indicate a set of characters. So it will match 1 or more repetitions of the characters from the set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

`(?<=\$)\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8uKXEh/4)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\$)` - positive lookbehind to find the position just preceded by a `$`
- `\d+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit
- `(?:,\d+)*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a `,` followed by 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - matches a `.` followed by 1+ digits. `?` in the end makes this decimal part optional